# Azure Machine Learning studio: Failed to parse parameter

Tags: azure, data-science, azure-machine-learning-service

I keep getting Error 002: Failed to parse parameter in the "Score Matchbox Recommender" box.

I'm using Azure's default "Recommender: Movie recommendation" sample project.

I've tried referring to an online video too, followed same steps but to no avail. Still getting error 002.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cNd_YRAsdk

Full error code below.

> requestId = 8ce5b273ae124cd5a5d872e5a509fe45 errorComponent=Module. taskStatusCode=400. {"Exception":{"ErrorId":"ParameterParsing","ErrorCode":"0002","ExceptionType":"ModuleException","Message":"Error 0002: Failed to parse parameter"}}Error: Error 0002: Failed to parse parameter Process exited with error code -2

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Can you show your code on how you call the API?

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply Jon.
I've taken screen shots of the experimental environment.
https://imgur.com/a/QNd0zSw

The model fails during this stage (before being able to get to API).
Greatly appreciate if anyone can share any insights cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure if you need three different recommender models, I think one would be just fine. Also, you may want to add an "Evaluate Recommender" module at the end of it, too.